# Im looking for way to make a ui-bootstrap type-ahead able to select multiple comma sepereated items

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757508/attempting-to-combine-angular-ui-bootstraps-typeahead-with-alert)

but instead of having alert boxes just having comma separated values in the input feild.

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you could try using [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2), which is a wrapper for [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)... which has tagging. Otherwise, take a look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693325/angularjs-typeahead-multi-select-tags).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm trying ui-select2 but I'm not very clear about how to use it. I will provide samples of what I have as a working typeahead and what I have done to try to get the select2 to work.

ui-bootstrap typeahead:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedItem.value" typeahead="item.value for item in items |filter:$viewValue| limitTo:8" typeahead-on-select="updateItem()" placeholder="select Item"/>
```

ui-select2 (can't load data.)

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="selectedItem.value" data-placeholder="Select Item">
 <option value=""></option>
  <option ng-repeat="item.value for item in items" value:"{{item.value}}>{{item.label}}</option>
</select>
```